# Is there a way to develop a Rational Team Concert (RTC) project in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, git, unix, rtc

I am a new hire and I prefer working in the UNIX environment, however the project I am on is developed in the IBM WebSphere environment - IBM WID connected up to RTC repo. Any way I can develop from UNIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My apologies, didn't read the title of the question - revising answer]

RTC has a commandline interface that works just fine on Linux.  The main usage of this interface is version control operations, linked to work items.  Reference guide for RTC v3 is here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v3r0m1/index.jsp.  Search for "Source control command line reference" (it's in the reference section of the Help), or the latest shipping release of RTC is v4 - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp.  Search for the same string "Source control command line reference".

You also have the option of using WID (a development environment based on Eclipse) directly in Linux. WID 7.0 supports Linux (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016959).

If you are using other versions of WID - search for the system requirements for that version to see if Linux is supported.

From a WID perspective - RTC is installed as an Eclipse plugin to the WID environment to provide the source code management, work item/task management and build capabilities.

As VonC rightly points out - you need to be aware of the cross-platform dependencies, but those should not prevent you from working with WID and RTC on a Linux/Unix platform.

Comment: Interesting reference to WID. +1

Answer (score 0):

"From Linux to Windows, Mac to mainframe, Eclipse to Visual Studio, we've got you covered", says [their site](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/). As far as I know, RTC consists of web software+UI (multiplatform), eclipse (multiplatform), websphere that runs on multiple platforms and source control that is supported on different platforms. Also, Linux/Unix is listed on their [supported environments](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/rtc/sysreq/). So yes, you should be able to develop from UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop on Linux, but be mindful of classic cross-platform issues like:

- [potential case problems](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/47355/how-insensitive-suggestions-about-rtc-naming-conventions): you could store
- [permissions not saved](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/48370/file-permissions-in-scm): RTC does not store/restore file permissions, except for the
  "execute" bit, which only applies to Unix systems, since Windows using
  the extension of the file to determine "executability", not an execute bit.
- [eol style](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/29972/linux-rtc-client-checking-in-read-only-dos-mode-files) (or [mixed eol](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/63732/mixing-line-delimiters-destroys-change-history)): the default EOL RTC assigns to text files is
  `PLATFORM`, and RTC will try to convert your text files end-of-lines.